# SQL Two tables count

Tags: mysql, left-join, mysql-workbench

I have two SQL tables, one is called X and one is called Y. Table X has two columns, street name and house number. Table Y also has two columns, street name and house number.

I am trying to create a query, that lets me count how many times a certain street name comes up,normally this would be very easy.

But here is the trick, upon some research, if you use count() when there is no instances of a given string in a column, it should return 0, but it doesn't.
Any help on how to make a count() in sql return 0 would be appreciated. Currently when I run the query, it returns 1 even if there are no instances of it in the table.

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT b.wing,count(b.wing),count(a.wing)
FROM  residents as a, rooms as b
WHERE b.wing = ( "Wing" OR  "East" OR "Split")
GROUP BY b.wing
```

**Result**

```
East      2     1
Split     1     1
West      1     1
```

**Expected Result**

```
East      2     0
Split     1     0
West      1     1
```

**Current Result with current  proposed solution**

```
East      1     1
Split     1     1
West      1     1
```

Problem: Split and East 2nd column should be returning 0 (there are no instances of them in the table)

**Sample Data:**

```
 residents
 name      wing    roomnum 
'justin', 'West', '400',     ( in this table there is only one entry)

 rooms
 wing    roomnum
 'East', '410', 
 'Split', '400', 
'West', '400', 
 'East', '400',
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data's & your query>

Comment: Do not you think that would be really helpful if you show us a query you are running now? And also how you run and fetch data from that query?

Comment: Sure give me a minute.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the implicit join. Do you have a way of explicitly joining rooms to residents?

Comment: what do you mean? i am very new to sql

Comment: Add sample data from residents and rooms and I'll demonstrate the potential problem with implicit joins.

Comment: Try and change your WHERE statement to: `WHERE b.wing = "Wing" OR b.wing = "East" OR b.wing = "Split"`

Comment: No it does not work. All of the results are wrong

Comment: Here you can see the difference between my suggestion and your current query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36c71d/1. You should also look into @P.Salmon's suggestion.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson personally, I prefer `IN ()` :)

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Me too. Just wanted the OP to see the difference :-)

Comment: I dont see the west wing, using the IN(), and if I change it to b.wing =, then I get 1 for everything, so back to suUARE ONE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have returned 0, if you had used a `JOIN` clause instead of cross-product of the 2 tables. If your table `residents` is related to the other via any of the columns, use a `LEFT JOIN` clause, so that `NULL` values are returned to get a `0` results.

An example would be similar to:

```
SELECT b.wing,count(b.wing),count(a.wing)
FROM rooms as b
LEFT JOIN residents as a
    ON a.roomnum = b.roomnum
        AND a.wing = b.wing
WHERE b.wing IN ( "Wing", "East", "Split")
GROUP BY b.wing
```

Comment: I appreicate your efforts, but that does not produce the correct results, It produces the exact incorrect answer. I have one west wing, and your results produces     east      1     1    west    1    1

Comment: How are the 2 tables related? What is your expected output? I used a single join condition, but the table structure shows 2.

Comment: does that help @hjpotter92

Comment: @jewstin sorry! that was supposed to be `LEFT JOIN`; and as I had said put the relations between table in the join clause. Check the recent edit above.

Comment: I got it, I made one minor change to your code, but it works!

Comment: WHERE b.wing = ( "Wing" OR "East" OR "Split")

Comment: No! Don't use `b.wing = (x or y or z)`. It is not the same as `wing = x or wing = y or wing = z`. Try adding a new wing data to your `rooms` table with `wing = 'something else'` and you'll see.

Comment: Ok I will try that, after I get my other code to work!